# Laravel, Can I auto logout (or) clear session after issuing oauth token (passport)

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel and Passport for API authentication, my front-end app is Javascript so I have to use **implicit-grant-tokens** type (/oauth/authorize?client_id=1&response_type=token), before I can get token I have to login at backend (Laravel) and it will redirect to my frontend app with token.

The problem is it still login at backend, if i want to logout, i have to come to backend and clear session and remove token in frontend.

I want Laravel to logout immediately after issue token, so if i want to logout I just need to remove token that I save in localStorage at frontend, don't need to worry about the backend.

P.S.

so far I've tried with `Auth::once()`, it doesn't work because after login it will redirect to `oauth/authorize` and `oauth/authorize` check if user login or not, if not it will redirect back to login again.

Comment: use `Auth:once` it doesn't create authenticated session, it is only for single request

Comment: I already try that, it doesn't work because after login it will redirect to `oauth/authorize` and `oauth/authorize` check if user login or not, if not it will redirect back to login.

Comment: you can delete the laravel session cookie